# java say only speaks the first word

Tags: 14.04, sound, java, text-to-speech

I have the following code:

```
public class ChatSystem {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpeakCommand sp = new SpeakCommand("hello master! How are you feeling today?");
        sp.execute();
    }
}

import java.io.IOException;

public class SpeakCommand implements CommandInterface{
    String message;
    public SpeakCommand(String content){
        message=content;
    }

    public void execute() {
        try {
            System.out.println("spd-say \"" +message+ "\" -p 100 -i 100 -t female1");
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("spd-say \"" +message+ "\" -p 100 -i 100 -t female1");


        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Which if executed result in my laptop saying "hello" in the correct voice (that is `-p 100 -i 100 -t female1 -r -40` is indeed passed to say). The printout also correctly states spd-say `"hello master! How are you feeling today?" -p 100 -i 100 -t female1` which if executed in the command line works. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try the `exec()` method with the `cmdarray` parameter (String[] containing the command and its arguments) instead of concatenating the command and its arguments to a single string. --> `exec(new String[]{"spd-say", message, "-p 100", "-i 100", "-t female1"})` I am not sure if this helps, but that's what I would try. Maybe you have to experiment a bit with the quotes or whether to split the switch-value-pairs...

Comment: That didn't seem to result in any output.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("spd-say \"" +message+ "\" -p 100 -i 100 -t female1");
```

with

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"spd-say",'\"'+message+'\"',"-p 100 -i 100 -t female1");
```

and it will work.
Cheers!